# how to pass user properties file to JMETER through commant prompt

Tags: properties, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using JMETER for load testing. I have large number of user properties in my plan. Its not recommended to pass all these through command prompt because of size issues. I am aware that we can put all the properties in some .properties file and use that file. Like we have the user.properties file in JMETER. But I want to make my own properties file and it should be loaded after the jmeter.properties file. Can anyone guide me how I can do that. 
I have gone through a link
http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-property-file-reader-a-custom-config-element/
But not getting how are the following steps to be done

```
Download this zip file which contains a jar file.


tag-jmeter-extn-1.0.zip (784 downloads)

Go to JMETER_HOME/lib/ext foler.
Place the jar file & Restart JMeter.
Once yo launch the JMeter, You will see ‘Property File Reader’ as given below.
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created the plugin. Did you place the jar file in the `/lib/ext` folder?
If yes, then close the jmeter and launch again. Under `Config Elements` - you would see `Property File Reader`. Give the path of the property file to be read. 
You can add as many Property File Reader elements as you want for each property file.

If you do not want to use any external plugin, you can simply pass the property files to the test as shown below.

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -p c/path/to/prop.properties
```

The main idea of using the plugin is to read the user property file during the design phase/GUI as well. `Property File Reader` will work in both GUI/non-GUI modes.

Comment: Hey hii.. Actually I was not able to download your plugin :( There is no download link there.

Comment: @RasikaKulkarni, Plz check now.

Comment: Thanks. Can download it now.

Comment: As you have written your own property reader, can you please guide me with other requirement. I want to modify the summary listener and add the values directly to database. I know we can create a summary.csv and then load that data to database. But I dont want to create the csv file, and directly take the data and add it to the database. Is it possible ?

Comment: While the test is running? or after the test?

Comment: After the test is run

Comment: The csv is not created after the test is run. It is created first when the test starts and is updated while the test is running. As you say You need to import the data into DB after the test is run, we need to store the somewhere in the meantime, rt? So we need the csv file for this. Or we can use Beanshell to import the data directly into the DB while the test is running.

Comment: Can i get the end summary result in the beanshell ? so that I can take that data and put it in the database

Comment: I dont want to create the csv file. That's the aim. What does JMETER do when it runs the summary listener ?

Comment: Can you not simply delete the CSV file once it is imported? It is not very easy to use beanshell listener to import the data into DB while the test is running.

Comment: Ok. But don't want to do while the test is running. The summary data goes in the database after the test is completed.

Comment: Then it might not be possible. there should be a file which has the data for the import. So CSV file is required. Only option is - you can delete programmatically after the import.